# AJAX Check if a div of an external file is empty

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following code that retrieves every 60 sec the content of a specific div (#livetick) and refresh another div (#liveticker) with that content.

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#liveticker").load('http://www.domain.com/livetickerr/ #livetick');
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#liveticker").load('http://www.domain.com/livetickerr/ #livetick');
       }, 60000);
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
  </script>
```

Also, the html code of div that is refreshed every 60 sec is:

```
<div class="liveticker" id="liveticker">   
            <b>Loading...</b>
</div>
```

My question is how can i hide the div "liveticker" if the return content of "livetick" div is empty?
I have already search about my question but i cant find a way to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a callback to run after you load the external source:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#liveticker").load('http://www.domain.com/livetickerr/ #livetick', function(response) {
    if ( response === "" )
    {
        $('#liveticker').html("");
    }
});
```

Of course, `response === ""` isn't a great conditional. Something more like,

```
$("#ticker_content", response).html() === ""
```

might serve you better. I don't know how the #livetick div is structured.

Comment: Thank u for the instant reply! I am not sure if the code u wrote, it will hide div code! I mean when if statement is true, the div must be hidden! not only the content of it!

Comment: That can be accomplished by changing the contents of the if statement to $('#liveticker').hide();